# Datatype creation in SQL for Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

Can i create my own datatype in SQL to use on an oracle database?

i tried creating an array or varchar2 : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW8Tk.png)
to be able to create a table with a column with "genre_list" datatype :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cFGM.png)

but when i tried to run this in sql developer i encountered this error message :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfXnD.png)

Comment: Please do not paste images of code. [Edit] your question and include the queries and error messages as text (formatted using markdown), not images.

Answer (score 0):

Create the data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE genre_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

Then create the table with a nested table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE book (
  id     NUMBER,
  isbn   VARCHAR2(20),
  genres genre_list
) NESTED TABLE genres STORE AS book__genres;
```